# The level set of Lipschitz functions

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

Suppose $u$: $R^N\to R$ is lipschitz, then do we have a.e. level set of $u$ has Lipschitz boundary? Is this anything to do with Sard theorem?

Sard theorem states that a.e. Level set of smooth function is a smooth manifold.

Comment: Why do you say Lipschitz *boundary*? BTW, you can find the most general version of Sard's Theorem that I know in Federer's GMT. I don't remember that it extends to the Lipschitz case, but I don't have the book here.

Comment: Apparently not. The paper [Structure of level sets and Sard-type properties
of Lipschitz maps](http://www.dm.unipi.it/~alberti/files/ricerca/2010-12/abc-LipSard.pdf) by Alberti, S. Bianchini, G. Crippa, gives some positive results about level sets, but notes: "there exist functions $f$ on the plane of class $C^{
1,α}$ with $α < 1$ such that every level set contains a cusp.". Unfortunately, they don't give an example or a reference.

Comment: But if $\alpha<1$ then it is not Lipschitz right?

Comment: $C^{1,\alpha}$ is better than Lipschitz: it means the first  derivative is in $C^{\alpha}$, in particular continuous, hence the function is locally Lipschitz. Also, please use `@` (I don't have to use it because the author of the post is always notified).

Comment: @Behaviour thanks, I understand now! However, my question comes from the coarea formula and I'll write more details for you tomorrow.

Comment: "more details tomorrow"?

Comment: "more details tomorrow"?